# python selenium multiple test cases

Tags: python, firefox, testing, selenium

I have the following code in python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from unittestzero import Assert
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
import unittest, time, re

class HomePageTest(unittest.TestCase):
    expected_title="  some title here "
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://somewebsite.com"
        self.verificationErrors = []

    def test_home_page(self):
        driver=self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        print "test some things here"




    def test_whatever(self):
        print "test some more things here"

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

My problem is after the function test_home_page, the firefox instance closes and opens again for the next test_whatever function. How can I do his so that all the test cases are executed from the same firefox instance.

Comment: any code in your `setUp`/`tearDown` will be run for *each* test case executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize the firefox driver in `__init__`:

```
class HomePageTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://somewebsite.com"
        self.verificationErrors = []

    ...

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 8):

Usually you want the browser to close between tests so that you start each test with a clean cache, localStorage, history database, etc. Closing the browser between tests does slow down the tests, but it saves in debug time because a test doesn't interact with the browser cache and  history of a previous test.

Comment: +1. And in the long run, clean browser instances between tests will actually enable you to _speed_ _up_ test execution by allowing tests to run concurrently. If you have several tests that rely on the state of the browser being preserved from test to test, you are forced to run them serially. However, if each test is able to run from a clean slate, you now have the ability run them all at the same time. For a suite of 5 test cases, each taking 60 seconds to complete, your total test time is reduced from 5 minutes to 1 minute. Imagine the savings if you have 1000 test cases!

Answer (score 3):

use `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass`

```
class HomePageTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def setUp(self):
        self.base_url = "https://somewebsite.com"
        self.verificationErrors = []

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.get(self.base_url)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def suite():  

    suite = unittest.TestSuite()  
    suite.addTest(HomePageTest("test_home_page"))  
    suite.addTest(HomePageTest("test_whatever"))  
    return suite  

if __name__ == "__main__":

    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite())
```

Run many testcase with the same Firefox instance.
Btw, i have a question hope someone could know it and answer to me.
How could i execute the same testcase in different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I think WebDriver Plus solves your problem. Here it is. http://webdriverplus.org/en/latest/browsers.html
You can reuse the same browser instance across all unit tests using this .

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

use `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` with `@classmethod` decorator.