# How to run selenium webdriver in parallel in internet explorer

Tags: selenium, testng

I m using a single test method which I feed from a data provider which can access different sheets of an excel file I m using keyword driven framework

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. It is not wise to run multiple isntances of selenium on the same pc. It will cause hell lot of problems but if you intend to do so then, you create multiple instances of the same driver and handle the driver sessions. But if you can execute on multiple computers then i would suggest to use selenium grid.

Answer (score 0):

You need a selenium grid. Selenium Grid allows you to have multiple slave and one host machine. So multiple instance can be kicked off at the same time. See [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) to start with the configuration.

Comment: I want to run parallely in the same PC

Comment: Instantiating more than one browser instances can probably be done but wouldn't be useful for testing. There is no way to control those tests on different browser instances of same. If test need to be run on different browsers but single instance of each that can be accomplished

Comment: @saifur who gave you this information ? we run multiple isntances of same browser and control them with ease.

Comment: @raynaya as I said this is from my knowledge. If you do that please provide the answer of this question so I can learn something as well. Thanks for mentioning it can be done

Comment: @saifur was your comment specific to ie ?  In IE it is not wise to run multiple on the same machine. Otherwise afaik you just need to create separate driver objects and use them. They are not static instances they will work independently. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16383443/888070 as well

Comment: @raynaya interesting information. But, my answer and as well as OP's question were specific to IE. However, it's a very good bit of information. Thanks for taking time to let me know if can be done

Comment: @Saifur This can be done on IE as well i believe but it is afterall IE.