# Selenium java - can we run selenium multiple instances at same time on server

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Details -
 Can we run the **multiple instances of selenium script at same time** 
 while running  multiple instances of selenium script at same time my script failed connection refused

AnyOne has the solution for it .

Answer (score 0):

You can try something called Selenium Grid.

> Selenium-Grid allows you run your tests on different machines against
>   different browsers in parallel. That is, running multiple tests at the
>   same time against different machines running different browsers and
>   operating systems. Essentially, Selenium-Grid support distributed test
>   execution. It allows for running your tests in a distributed test
>   execution environment.

You can find more on the following website= https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp.

Also, check out this response as well. It was for a similar question= [Running multiple Selenium tests at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005672/running-multiple-selenium-tests-at-the-same-time)