# How to open multiple instances of Firefox using python?

Tags: python, selenium

Can someone please help me on how to open multiple instances of firefox using selenium in python.

I wrote the following code and it does open multiple instances but I would want to keep all the references to the browser so I can access each browser to do specific tasks and should be able to Quit all the browsers once the test is done.

```
class LoadTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    i = 0
    while (i < 2):
      self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
      self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
      self.base_url = "http://example.com/"
      self.verificationErrors = []
      self.accept_next_alert = True
      driver = self.driver
      url = "http://example.com/"
      driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
      i = i + 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python selenium multiple test cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049505/python-selenium-multiple-test-cases)

Answer (score 0):

For one thing:

```
for i in range(2):
    ...
```

is much neater and less error-prone than:

```
i = 0
while i < 2:
    ...
    i = i + 1 # or just 'i += 1'
```

But your main problem is that each time through the loop you *replace* the previous `webdriver`, losing access to it:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Instead, consider a list:

```
self.drivers = []
for i in range(2):
    self.drivers.append(webdriver.Firefox())
    ...
```

now you retain access to all of them.

Comment: Two things: 1. Code is very hard to read in the comments (particularly Python, where indentation matters). 2: Your description of the problem is useless. However, the issue is clear; you need to `get` and `quit` each instance in the list *separately* - you can't just call the method on the list and expect it to work.