# Rum multiple test cases using python selenium webdriver on same web browser session

Tags: selenium, python-unittest

I have following code here:

```
import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

class MyTest1(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver = cls.driver
        driver.get("https://somewebsite.com")
        print "login the website"

    def test_UI_login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        print "test some things here"

    def test_duplicate_client(self):
        driver = self.driver
        print "test some things here"


    def tearDown(cls):
        cls.driver.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Problem I am facing is ,
After first function test_UI_login, the firefox instance closes. How can I execute multiple test cases from the same Firefox instance in unittest using selenium.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you also annotate tearDown with `@classmethod`?

Comment: It didn't work out if we annotate tearDown with @classmethod

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049505/python-selenium-multiple-test-cases)

you must initialize the driver in `__init__` .

Comment: I tried as you suggested. But,I am getting below error, 
typeerror __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

    class MyTest1(unittest.TestCase):
        def __init__(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            driver = self.driver

Comment: You must declare `__init__(cls, tests)` Sorry for the misunderstanding, it's been a while since I used it. It looks like selenium adds an additional parameter in the latest versions.

Comment: Tried the method as suggested you(def __init__(cls, tests)), noticed below error
**'MyTest1' object has no attribute '_testMethodName'**

Comment: Oh, sorry. Forgot to mention that you have to implicitly call the superclasses __init__ if you overwrite it. So adding `    unittest.TestCase.__init__(cls, tests)` as the first line in your __init__ should work (At least it does for me) :-).

Answer (score 0):

Assign the webdriver in `__init__()`, but don't forget to call `super.__init__()` to not break the tests mechanism:

```
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```